# How do I manage to run godog in Gitlab?

Tags: go, gitlab-ci

When I run godog in Gitlab i get the following error message:

> failed to compile testmain package: exit status 2 - output: /tmp/go- >build1205394271/b001/_testmain.go:5:2: import path contains invalid character ':': >"https:/github.com/steinko/GodogTutorial/godogs"
> /tmp/go-build1205394271/b001/_testmain.go:23:4: undefined: _tes

My gitlab-ci.yml file looks like this

```
image: golang:latest

variables:
  REPO_NAME: https://github.com/steinko/GodogTutorial

before_script:
  - mkdir -p $GOPATH/src/$(dirname $REPO_NAME)
  - ln -svf $CI_PROJECT_DIR $GOPATH/src/$REPO_NAME
  - export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/go/bin
  - cd $GOPATH/src/$REPO_NAME/hello
  - echo $HOME
  - echo $PATH
  - echo $GOPATH

stages:
  - integration

test-integration:
  stage: integration
  script:
    - go test

test-acceptance:
  stage: integration
  script:
    - go get github.com/cucumber/godog/cmd/godog
    - cd ../godogs
    - godog
```

the go test file looks like this

```
package main

import (
         "os"
         "github.com/cucumber/godog"
         "github.com/stretchr/testify/assert"
         "testing"
         "fmt"
       )


func applicationIsDeveloped() error {
    return nil
}


func display(expectedMessage string) error {
    
    var actualMessage =  hello("Stein")
    return  assertExpectedAndActual(
        assert.Equal, expectedMessage, actualMessage,
        "Expected messag to be %d  but actualMessage  is %d", 
        expectedMessage, actualMessage,
    )
    
}


func runApplication() error {
    return nil
}


func InitializeScenario(ctx *godog.ScenarioContext) {
    
    ctx.Step(`^application is developed$`, applicationIsDeveloped)
    ctx.Step(`^display "([^"]*)"$`, display)
    ctx.Step(`^run application$`, runApplication)
    
}

//Linking Godog to testify

func TestMain(m *testing.M) {
    
        status := godog.TestSuite{
                    ScenarioInitializer: InitializeScenario,       
                  }.Run()
        os.Exit(status)
}


func assertExpectedAndActual(a expectedAndActualAssertion, expected, actual interface{}, msgAndArgs ...interface{}) error{
    
    var t asserter
    a(&t, expected, actual, msgAndArgs...)
    return t.err
    
}


type expectedAndActualAssertion func(t assert.TestingT, expected, actual interface{}, msgAndArgs ...interface{}) bool


type asserter struct {
    err error
}


func (a *asserter) Errorf(format string, args ...interface{}) {
    
    a.err = fmt.Errorf(format, args...)
    
}
```

and the go.mod file looks like this

```
module godogs

go 1.16

require (
    github.com/cucumber/godog v0.11.0
    github.com/spf13/pflag v1.0.5 // indirect
    github.com/stretchr/testify v1.6.1
)
```

The gitlab log looks like this

```
Running with gitlab-runner 14.0.1 (c1edb478)
  on docker-auto-scale ed2dce3a
  feature flags: FF_SKIP_DOCKER_MACHINE_PROVISION_ON_CREATION_FAILURE:true
Resolving secrets
00:00
Preparing the "docker+machine" executor
00:29
Using Docker executor with image golang:latest ...
Pulling docker image golang:latest ...
Using docker image sha256:ee23292e282684136ded9a63f7f96b3aea50e19e9a5cec684aa7d107d6e1cc30 for golang:latest with digest golang@sha256:91b3c5472d9a2ef12f3165aa8979825a5d8b059720b00412f89fc465a04aaa0c ...
Preparing environment
00:02
Running on runner-ed2dce3a-project-27773316-concurrent-0 via runner-ed2dce3a-srm-1625150452-0b609475...
Getting source from Git repository
00:02
$ eval "$CI_PRE_CLONE_SCRIPT"
Fetching changes with git depth set to 50...
Initialized empty Git repository in /builds/steinKo/GodogTutorial/.git/
Created fresh repository.
Checking out a0b51604 as 3-implement-a-equal-assert-in-the-hello-world...
Skipping Git submodules setup
Executing "step_script" stage of the job script
00:26
Using docker image sha256:ee23292e282684136ded9a63f7f96b3aea50e19e9a5cec684aa7d107d6e1cc30 for golang:latest with digest golang@sha256:91b3c5472d9a2ef12f3165aa8979825a5d8b059720b00412f89fc465a04aaa0c ...
$ mkdir -p $GOPATH/src/$(dirname $REPO_NAME)
$ ln -svf $CI_PROJECT_DIR $GOPATH/src/$REPO_NAME
'/go/src/https://github.com/steinko/GodogTutorial' -> '/builds/steinKo/GodogTutorial'
$ export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/go/bin
$ cd $GOPATH/src/$REPO_NAME/hello
$ echo $HOME
/root
$ echo $PATH
/go/bin:/usr/local/go/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/root/go/bin
$ go get github.com/cucumber/godog/cmd/godog
go: downloading github.com/cucumber/godog v0.11.0
go: downloading github.com/spf13/cobra v1.1.1
go: downloading github.com/spf13/pflag v1.0.5
go: downloading github.com/cucumber/messages-go/v10 v10.0.3
go: downloading github.com/inconshreveable/mousetrap v1.0.0
go: downloading github.com/cucumber/gherkin-go/v11 v11.0.0
go: downloading github.com/hashicorp/go-memdb v1.3.0
go: downloading github.com/gofrs/uuid v3.3.0+incompatible
go: downloading github.com/gogo/protobuf v1.3.1
go: downloading github.com/hashicorp/go-immutable-radix v1.3.0
go: downloading github.com/hashicorp/golang-lru v0.5.4
go: downloading github.com/gofrs/uuid v1.2.0
go get: added github.com/cucumber/godog v0.11.0
$ cd ../godogs
$ godog
failed to compile testmain package: exit status 2 - output: /tmp/go-build1205394271/b001/_testmain.go:5:2: import path contains invalid character ':': "https:/github.com/steinko/GodogTutorial/godogs"
/tmp/go-build1205394271/b001/_testmain.go:23:4: undefined: _test
Cleaning up file based variables
00:01

ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

How do I fix this error?

Answer (score 0):

RE: `failed to compile testmain package: exit status 2 - output: /tmp/go-build1205394271/b001/_testmain.go:5:2: import path contains invalid character ':': "https:/github.com/steinko/GodogTutorial/godogs"`

An import path should not include `https://`

You likely need to use `import "github.com/steinko/GodogTutorial/godogs"`